# Get number of inserts, updates, deletes for entity using org.hibernate.SessionFactory per Session per thread

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following scenario:

I have one controller which based on a path variable calls a different service.

In every service there is a transactional method where some import logic is happening(call one external api, get a csv file, parse it, convert it to entity and save it in database).

Additionally in every service I want to keep statistics of how many entities will be updated, inserted and deleted. For that reason I am using the `org.hibernate.SessionFactory` . One example of how I am using that is:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class MarketReportImporterImpl extends Support implements MarketReportImporter {

@Override
@Transactional
public void importMarketReports(ImporterLog importerLog) {
    try {
        String export = getCsvFile();
        Session session = getCurrentSessionAndClearSessionFactoryStatistics();
        // parse the csv and save the entities
        flushSession(session);
        setSuccessfulImport(session, importerLog);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Failed to import market reports. Unable to parse export", e);
        getTelemetryClient().trackException(e);
        importerLogService.setFailedImport(importerLog, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

and the methods `getCurrentSessionAndClearSessionFactoryStatistics()` and `setSuccessfulImport(session, importerLog);` are in the `Support` class:

```
@Component
public abstract class Support {

private final ImporterLogService importerLogService;

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

public Support(ImporterLogService importerLogService) {
    this.importerLogService = importerLogService;
}

public void flushSession(Session session) {
    session.flush();
}

public void setSuccessfulImport(Session session, ImporterLog importerLog) {

    Statistics statistics = session.getSessionFactory().getStatistics();
    int entityInsertCount = (int) statistics.getEntityInsertCount();
    int entityDeleteCount = (int) statistics.getEntityDeleteCount();
    int entityUpdateCount = (int) statistics.getEntityUpdateCount();
    importerLogService.setSuccessfulImport(importerLog, entityUpdateCount, entityDeleteCount, entityInsertCount);
}

public Session getCurrentSessionAndClearSessionFactoryStatistics() {
    Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = session.getSessionFactory();
    sessionFactory.getStatistics().clear();
    return session;
}
```

This works perfectly fine when calling it for one importer. But If from the frontend I am calling quickly two importers (meaning two threads run in parallel) there will be mix in the results. The `session.getSessionFactory().getStatistics();` will have mix results from the first importer and from the second importer and I want to have a clear result only for the current session. For example service A and service B are running in parallel and in service A I am saving entities of type `aa` and in service B of type `bb`. In each service I want to know how many entities are saved, updated or deleted meaning in service A -> how many of type `aa` and in service B -> how many of type `bb` . As I understand every thread should open a session on it's own and then for every session I should get the correct sessionFactory and the correct results. But as it turns out this sessionFactory I guess (not sure in this statement) it belongs to every session and that is why I have mix results.

My question is if there is a way to separate somehow the sessionFactory and have clear vision of which entity how many times is saved,deleted,updated even in multithreaded environment.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the statistics of a session, then call the `getStatistics()` method on `session`, which will give you the `SessionStatistics`. A `SessionFactory` should only exist once and statistics there are across all sessions.

Comment: I tried getting the information using the `SessionStatistics` but I wasn't able to get the number of inserts, deletes or creates. There are some methods like: `getEntityCount`, `getCollectionCount` and `getEntityKeys` which aren't giving the needed information. Or am I missing something?

Comment: These are the statistics that are collected on a per-session basis. You can collect custom metrics if you want by implementing a custom `Interceptor`: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#events

Comment: I did that already, created a custom `Interceptor` but wasn't able to add a spring managed bean so I can save the statistics and that's why I went with this approach.

Comment: You could propagate the context through a `ThreadLocal`. I think that if you want to use a Spring bean as interceptor, you'll have create a custom bean factory for the `EntityManagerFactory`

Comment: What I did and it's working in the implementation that is above is that in the Component that is deciding which importer to be called based on the PATH variable, made that method synchronised. So now there won't be a possibility for two threads to execute two importers in parallel so the SessionFactory will give me clear results. But will check the `EntitymanagerFactory` to see how it's working.